# HTML5 canvas webgl, cant get a cube to be drawn

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, glsl, webgl

I'm trying to make a program that draws cubes on the screen in a html5 canvas using js and webgl. I want to make it so I can just make a new cube whenever I do `webgl.makeCupe()` kinda like how with `canvasRendering2D.fillRect` works, but for some reason that isnt working, I know webgl works because it colors the background, I don't get any errors but there isn't anything drawn on the cube (beside the background)

```js
let ARRAY_TYPE = (typeof Float32Array !== 'undefined') ? Float32Array : Array;
 
 function create() {
  let out = new ARRAY_TYPE(16);
  if(ARRAY_TYPE != Float32Array) {
    out[1] = 0;
    out[2] = 0;
    out[3] = 0;
    out[4] = 0;
    out[6] = 0;
    out[7] = 0;
    out[8] = 0;
    out[9] = 0;
    out[11] = 0;
    out[12] = 0;
    out[13] = 0;
    out[14] = 0;
  }
  out[0] = 1;
  out[5] = 1;
  out[10] = 1;
  out[15] = 1;
  return out;
}

function perspective(out, fovy, aspect, near, far) {
  let f = 1.0 / Math.tan(fovy / 2), nf;
  out[0] = f / aspect;
  out[1] = 0;
  out[2] = 0;
  out[3] = 0;
  out[4] = 0;
  out[5] = f;
  out[6] = 0;
  out[7] = 0;
  out[8] = 0;
  out[9] = 0;
  out[11] = -1;
  out[12] = 0;
  out[13] = 0;
  out[15] = 0;
  if (far !== null && far !== Infinity) {
    nf = 1 / (near - far);
    out[10] = (far + near) * nf;
    out[14] = (2 * far * near) * nf;
  } else {
    out[10] = -1;
    out[14] = -2 * near;
  }
  return out;
}

 function translate(out, a, v) {
  let x = v[0], y = v[1], z = v[2];
  let a00, a01, a02, a03;
  let a10, a11, a12, a13;
  let a20, a21, a22, a23;

  if (a === out) {
    out[12] = a[0] * x + a[4] * y + a[8] * z + a[12];
    out[13] = a[1] * x + a[5] * y + a[9] * z + a[13];
    out[14] = a[2] * x + a[6] * y + a[10] * z + a[14];
    out[15] = a[3] * x + a[7] * y + a[11] * z + a[15];
  } else {
    a00 = a[0]; a01 = a[1]; a02 = a[2]; a03 = a[3];
    a10 = a[4]; a11 = a[5]; a12 = a[6]; a13 = a[7];
    a20 = a[8]; a21 = a[9]; a22 = a[10]; a23 = a[11];

    out[0] = a00; out[1] = a01; out[2] = a02; out[3] = a03;
    out[4] = a10; out[5] = a11; out[6] = a12; out[7] = a13;
    out[8] = a20; out[9] = a21; out[10] = a22; out[11] = a23;

    out[12] = a00 * x + a10 * y + a20 * z + a[12];
    out[13] = a01 * x + a11 * y + a21 * z + a[13];
    out[14] = a02 * x + a12 * y + a22 * z + a[14];
    out[15] = a03 * x + a13 * y + a23 * z + a[15];
  }

  return out;
}
//shaders

const shaders = {
  vertex: `
    precision mediump float;
    
    attribute vec4 avertPosition;
    attribute vec4 avertColor;
    
    varying vec4 vfragColor;
    
    uniform mat4 umodelMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uprojectionMatrix;
    
    void main()
    {
      vfragColor = avertColor;
      gl_Position  =  uprojectionMatrix * umodelMatrix * avertPosition;
    }
    `,
  fragment:
    `
    precision mediump float;
    
    varying vec4 vfragColor;
    void main()
    {
      gl_FragColor = vfragColor;
    }
    `
};

//cube class

class Cube {
  constructor(gl){
    
    this.gl = gl;
    
    this.buffers;
    
   
    
  }
  setUp(){

    const positionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
  
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  
  
    const positions = [
      // Front face
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
  
      // Back face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
  
      // Top face
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
  
      // Bottom face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
  
      // Right face
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
  
      // Left face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    ];
  
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const faceColors = [
      [1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
      [1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0],
      [0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0],
      [0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0],
      [1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0],
      [1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0],
    ];
  
  
    var colors = [];
  
    for (var j = 0; j < faceColors.length; ++j) {
      const c = faceColors[j];
  
      colors = colors.concat(c, c, c, c);
    }
  
    const colorBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
  
    const indices = [
      0,  1,  2,      0,  2,  3,    // front
      4,  5,  6,      4,  6,  7,    // back
      8,  9,  10,     8,  10, 11,   // top
      12, 13, 14,     12, 14, 15,   // bottom
      16, 17, 18,     16, 18, 19,   // right
      20, 21, 22,     20, 22, 23,   // left
    ];
  
  
    const indexBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
  
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Uint16Array(indices), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      
    this.buffers = {
      position: positionBuffer,
      color: colorBuffer,
      indices: indexBuffer,
    };
    
  }
}

//webgl class

class WebglProgram {
 constructor(canvas){
  
  this.gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  
  this.program;
  
  this.shaders = {};
  
  this.cubes = [];
  
 }
 
 async setUp(){
  
  if (!this.gl) {
   log('WebGL not supported, falling back on experimental-webgl');
   this.gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  }
  
  if (!this.gl) {
   log('Your browser does not support WebGL');
   return null;
  }
  
  let vertexShader  = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  let fragmentShader = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  
  this.gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, shaders.vertex);
  this.gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, shaders.fragment);
  
  
  this.program = this.gl.createProgram();
  
  
  [vertexShader, fragmentShader].forEach(shader => {
  
   this.gl.compileShader(shader);
  
   if (!this.gl.getShaderParameter(shader, this.gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    error(`ERROR compiling a shader!`, this.gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    this.gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return;
   }
   
   this.gl.attachShader(this.program, shader);
  
  });
  
  this.gl.linkProgram(this.program);
  
  
  if (!this.gl.getProgramParameter(this.program, this.gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
   error('ERROR linking program!', this.gl.getProgramInfoLog(this.program));
   return;
  }
  
  //Delete later since its extisnisve
  
  this.gl.validateProgram(this.program);
  if (!this.gl.getProgramParameter(this.program, this.gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
   error('ERROR validating program!', this.gl.getProgramInfoLog(this.program));
   return;
  }
  
  
  this.shaders.attributes = {
    positionAttrib : this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'avertPosition'),
    colorAttrib   : this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'avertColor'),
  };
  
  this.shaders.uniforms = {
    modelMatrix      : this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'umodelMatrix'),
    projectionMatrix : this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'uprojectionMatrix'),
  };
  
  return "Webgl Set Up";
 }
 
 clear(color){
  
  this.gl.clearColor(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);
  this.gl.clearDepth(1);
  
  this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  
  return "Cleared";
 }
 
 makeCube(){

  let newCube = new Cube(this.gl);
    
    newCube.setUp();
  
  this.cubes.push(newCube);
  
  return "FillRect called";
  
 }
 
 render(){
  for (let i = 0; i < this.cubes.length; i++) {

   
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.cubes[i].buffers.positionBuffer);
   this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(
     this.shaders.attributes.positionAttrib,
     3,
     this.gl.FLOAT,
     this.gl.FALSE,
     0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
     0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
   );
  
   this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.shaders.attributes.positionAttrib);
   

   
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.cubes[i].buffers.colorBuffer);
   this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(
     this.shaders.attributes.colorAttrib,
     4,
     this.gl.FLOAT,
     this.gl.FALSE,
     0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
     0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
   );
  
   this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.shaders.attributes.colorAttrib);
   
   
   this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.cubes[i].buffers.indices);
    
   this.gl.useProgram(this.program);
   
      const projectionMatrix = create();
      const modelMatrix  = create();
      
      
      const fieldOfView = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
      const aspect = this.gl.canvas.clientWidth / this.gl.canvas.clientHeight;
      const zNear = 0.1;
      const zFar = 100.0;

  
      perspective(projectionMatrix,
                   fieldOfView,
                   aspect,
                   zNear,
                   zFar);
                   
      translate(modelMatrix,
        modelMatrix,
        [0.0, 0.0, -6.0]
        );
      

      this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
          this.shaders.uniforms.projectionMatrix,
          false,
          projectionMatrix);
          
      this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
          this.shaders.uniforms.modelMatrix,
          false,
          modelMatrix);
          
      this.gl.drawElements(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 36, this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
      
          
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id = "webglCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
      onload = function(){

        let canvas = document.querySelector("#webglCanvas")

        let webgl = new WebglProgram(canvas)

        canvas.width = 500;
        canvas.height = 500;

        webgl.setUp()

        .then(()=>{
          webgl.gl.viewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
          webgl.makeCube()
          loop(webgl)
        })
      }

      function loop(webgl){
        function draw(){
          webgl.clear([1, 1, 0, 1])
          
          webgl.render()

          requestAnimationFrame(draw)

        }
        requestAnimationFrame(draw)
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: alrighty added the code in the question, didnt know how to use snipper-gman before so thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should do is check [the JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)

The code you posted shows an error and you should try to fix that error

[image]

Seeing the error above is about no buffers being bound I looked at the code for the place it's binding buffers. I put a breakpoint there [in the debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)

Inspecting the values I see you were using `positionBuffer` and `colorBuffer` but they are called just `position` and `color`

[image]

Fixing those something gets drawn.

```js
let ARRAY_TYPE = (typeof Float32Array !== 'undefined') ? Float32Array : Array;

function create() {
  let out = new ARRAY_TYPE(16);
  if (ARRAY_TYPE != Float32Array) {
    out[1] = 0;
    out[2] = 0;
    out[3] = 0;
    out[4] = 0;
    out[6] = 0;
    out[7] = 0;
    out[8] = 0;
    out[9] = 0;
    out[11] = 0;
    out[12] = 0;
    out[13] = 0;
    out[14] = 0;
  }
  out[0] = 1;
  out[5] = 1;
  out[10] = 1;
  out[15] = 1;
  return out;
}

function perspective(out, fovy, aspect, near, far) {
  let f = 1.0 / Math.tan(fovy / 2),
    nf;
  out[0] = f / aspect;
  out[1] = 0;
  out[2] = 0;
  out[3] = 0;
  out[4] = 0;
  out[5] = f;
  out[6] = 0;
  out[7] = 0;
  out[8] = 0;
  out[9] = 0;
  out[11] = -1;
  out[12] = 0;
  out[13] = 0;
  out[15] = 0;
  if (far !== null && far !== Infinity) {
    nf = 1 / (near - far);
    out[10] = (far + near) * nf;
    out[14] = (2 * far * near) * nf;
  } else {
    out[10] = -1;
    out[14] = -2 * near;
  }
  return out;
}

function translate(out, a, v) {
  let x = v[0],
    y = v[1],
    z = v[2];
  let a00, a01, a02, a03;
  let a10, a11, a12, a13;
  let a20, a21, a22, a23;

  if (a === out) {
    out[12] = a[0] * x + a[4] * y + a[8] * z + a[12];
    out[13] = a[1] * x + a[5] * y + a[9] * z + a[13];
    out[14] = a[2] * x + a[6] * y + a[10] * z + a[14];
    out[15] = a[3] * x + a[7] * y + a[11] * z + a[15];
  } else {
    a00 = a[0];
    a01 = a[1];
    a02 = a[2];
    a03 = a[3];
    a10 = a[4];
    a11 = a[5];
    a12 = a[6];
    a13 = a[7];
    a20 = a[8];
    a21 = a[9];
    a22 = a[10];
    a23 = a[11];

    out[0] = a00;
    out[1] = a01;
    out[2] = a02;
    out[3] = a03;
    out[4] = a10;
    out[5] = a11;
    out[6] = a12;
    out[7] = a13;
    out[8] = a20;
    out[9] = a21;
    out[10] = a22;
    out[11] = a23;

    out[12] = a00 * x + a10 * y + a20 * z + a[12];
    out[13] = a01 * x + a11 * y + a21 * z + a[13];
    out[14] = a02 * x + a12 * y + a22 * z + a[14];
    out[15] = a03 * x + a13 * y + a23 * z + a[15];
  }

  return out;
}
//shaders

const shaders = {
  vertex: `
    precision mediump float;
    
    attribute vec4 avertPosition;
    attribute vec4 avertColor;
    
    varying vec4 vfragColor;
    
    uniform mat4 umodelMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uprojectionMatrix;
    
    void main()
    {
      vfragColor = avertColor;
      gl_Position  =  uprojectionMatrix * umodelMatrix * avertPosition;
    }
    `,
  fragment: `
    precision mediump float;
    
    varying vec4 vfragColor;
    void main()
    {
      gl_FragColor = vfragColor;
    }
    `
};

//cube class

class Cube {
  constructor(gl) {

    this.gl = gl;

    this.buffers;



  }
  setUp() {

    const positionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();

    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);


    const positions = [
      // Front face
      -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
      1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
      1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,

      // Back face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
      1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
      1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

      // Top face
      -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      1.0, 1.0, -1.0,

      // Bottom face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,

      // Right face
      1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
      1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      1.0, -1.0, 1.0,

      // Left face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    ];

    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const faceColors = [
      [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
      [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
      [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
      [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
      [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
      [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    ];


    var colors = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < faceColors.length; ++j) {
      const c = faceColors[j];

      colors = colors.concat(c, c, c, c);
    }

    const colorBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    const indices = [
      0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, // front
      4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, // back
      8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, // top
      12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, // bottom
      16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // right
      20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23, // left
    ];


    const indexBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Uint16Array(indices), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.buffers = {
      position: positionBuffer,
      color: colorBuffer,
      indices: indexBuffer,
    };

  }
}

//webgl class

class WebglProgram {
  constructor(canvas) {

    this.gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    this.program;

    this.shaders = {};

    this.cubes = [];

  }

  async setUp() {

    if (!this.gl) {
      log('WebGL not supported, falling back on experimental-webgl');
      this.gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
    }

    if (!this.gl) {
      log('Your browser does not support WebGL');
      return null;
    }

    let vertexShader = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    let fragmentShader = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    this.gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, shaders.vertex);
    this.gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, shaders.fragment);


    this.program = this.gl.createProgram();


    [vertexShader, fragmentShader].forEach(shader => {

      this.gl.compileShader(shader);

      if (!this.gl.getShaderParameter(shader, this.gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        error(`ERROR compiling a shader!`, this.gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        this.gl.deleteShader(shader);
        return;
      }

      this.gl.attachShader(this.program, shader);

    });

    this.gl.linkProgram(this.program);


    if (!this.gl.getProgramParameter(this.program, this.gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      error('ERROR linking program!', this.gl.getProgramInfoLog(this.program));
      return;
    }

    //Delete later since its extisnisve

    this.gl.validateProgram(this.program);
    if (!this.gl.getProgramParameter(this.program, this.gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
      error('ERROR validating program!', this.gl.getProgramInfoLog(this.program));
      return;
    }


    this.shaders.attributes = {
      positionAttrib: this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'avertPosition'),
      colorAttrib: this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'avertColor'),
    };

    this.shaders.uniforms = {
      modelMatrix: this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'umodelMatrix'),
      projectionMatrix: this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'uprojectionMatrix'),
    };

    return "Webgl Set Up";
  }

  clear(color) {

    this.gl.clearColor(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);
    this.gl.clearDepth(1);

    this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    return "Cleared";
  }

  makeCube() {

    let newCube = new Cube(this.gl);

    newCube.setUp();

    this.cubes.push(newCube);

    return "FillRect called";

  }

  render() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cubes.length; i++) {


      this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.cubes[i].buffers.position);
      this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        this.shaders.attributes.positionAttrib,
        3,
        this.gl.FLOAT,
        this.gl.FALSE,
        0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
        0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
      );

      this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.shaders.attributes.positionAttrib);



      this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.cubes[i].buffers.color);
      this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        this.shaders.attributes.colorAttrib,
        4,
        this.gl.FLOAT,
        this.gl.FALSE,
        0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
        0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
      );

      this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.shaders.attributes.colorAttrib);


      this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.cubes[i].buffers.indices);

      this.gl.useProgram(this.program);

      const projectionMatrix = create();
      const modelMatrix = create();


      const fieldOfView = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
      const aspect = this.gl.canvas.clientWidth / this.gl.canvas.clientHeight;
      const zNear = 0.1;
      const zFar = 100.0;


      perspective(projectionMatrix,
        fieldOfView,
        aspect,
        zNear,
        zFar);

      translate(modelMatrix,
        modelMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -6.0]
      );


      this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
        this.shaders.uniforms.projectionMatrix,
        false,
        projectionMatrix);

      this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
        this.shaders.uniforms.modelMatrix,
        false,
        modelMatrix);

      this.gl.drawElements(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 36, this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


    }
  }
}

function main() {

  let canvas = document.querySelector("#webglCanvas")

  let webgl = new WebglProgram(canvas)

  canvas.width = 500;
  canvas.height = 500;

  webgl.setUp()

    .then(() => {
      webgl.gl.viewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
      webgl.makeCube()
      loop(webgl)
    })
}

function loop(webgl) {
  function draw() {
    webgl.clear([1, 1, 0, 1])

    webgl.render()

    requestAnimationFrame(draw)

  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="webglCanvas"></canvas>
```

Note you might be able to catch these types of errors by using a [webgl debug context](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Debugging). It's a library that wraps WebGL and checks for errors. The link above also shows how to check for passing `undefined` which is what happens when there is a typo like the one above.

Also just in case check out [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much. I am actually on a school chromebook which blocks the console, so I made a custom console which wrights errors on the screen, guess I forgot to add warning hehe. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

WebGLRenderingContext {} is a common problem in html animation. If you are getting the error message “WebGL Disabled” it is possible that:

- You may need to close your browser and force restart your computer
- Your browser needs to be updated
- WebGL and hardware acceleration were disabled in your browser
- A browser plug-in disabled WebGL
- An IT organization has disabled WebGL on your machine
- Your machine’s hardware does not support WebGL

Comment: Plagiarized from https://adobespark.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000356593-I-am-getting-a-WebGL-error-message-